# Searching in files that have space in their name

Tags: bash

This is from a script that gets in first argument a word to search and then list of files to search in that word.
For example how I run it: `./my_script book *`.

```
for file in ${*:2}; do
    if [[ -f "$file" ]]; then
        search_file "$1" $file
    fi
```

(search_file) is a function defined above.
The problem is that it skips the files that have spaces in their names. I guess it's because `${*:2}`, so what should I write in there?

By  the way - should I write `$file` or `"$file"` in the third line?

Comment: Have you tried quoting your $file? `"$file"`? I think you should do that first.

Comment: @kenorb it doesn't work, I tried

Comment: Can you paste into your question few first lines of search_file function, how do you parse the arguments?

Comment: Use `for file in "${@:2}"; do`. Also, when you use the variable `file`, use it with quotes: e.g., your third line should be `search_file "$1" "$file"`. (Funny that you used quotes in `[[ -f "$file" ]]` where it's not needed).

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf why it's not needed there? Can it give a wrong result if I use quotes if it's not needed there? how can I decide?

Comment: Don't worry, it won't give you a wrong result if you use quotes in `[[ -f "$file" ]]`. The manual states that _Word splitting and filename expansion are not performed on the words between the `[[` and `]]`._ (but if you're not sure, just don't think too much and use quotes!).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `"$@"` (quoted) instead of unquoted `$*`, and be sure to quote `$file` wherever it is used.

```
for file in "${@:2}"; do
    if [[ -f "$file" ]]; then
        search_file "$1" "$file"
    fi
```

Slightly cleaner would be to use `shift` to remove the first argument from the set of positional parameters, so that you can simply iterate over `"$@"` without using the substring expansion operator.

```
first=$1
shift
for file in "$@"; do
    if [[ -f "$file" ]]; do
        search_file "$first" "$file"
    fi
```

(In fact, you can shorten the for loop to `for file; do`, since iterating over the positional parameters is the default action with no `in` list.)

Comment: thanks. I choose this answer because its alters my script and not the way you should use it.

Answer (score 0):

run your script as below (put the * in single quotes), this should solve your problem if files have space or non printable chracters in its name

```
./my_script book '*'
```

using "$file" is better than $file

Comment: I see, if I had a file "shelf 2" it was looking for "shelf" file and "2" file. It worked as you say, only when I put "$file" too, thanks.